# Question about Calculus problem.

Tags: calculus

The problem is this:
Every Differential function $f(x)$ which $x\in R$ is satisfied with the following:
 
 
$f(x+y) \geq f(x) + f(y)-(\sin(x)\sin(y)-1)^2$
 
$f(0) \geq 1, f'(0) = 1$
 
 
then, what's $f'(3\pi)$? 
 
 
I got $f(0+0) \geq f(0) + f(0)-(\sin(0)\sin(0)-1)^2$, so $f(0) = 1$. But I can't solve this problem more than this. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trick that I can think of (by taking derivative with respect to x:)

> $f'(x+y)\geq f'(x)-2\sin(x)\cos(y)$

So $f'(x)=f'(0+x)\geq f'(0)-2\sin(0)\cos(x)=f'(0)=1$

Comment: An inequality for a function does not translate to the inequality for the derivative.

Comment: The other part is pretty useless, I fixed it